# Record if conditional is never met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am iterating through two dataframes (one for orders and one for current amount) to effectively update the sum when an amount goes out. I've got the loop below:

```
##iterates through orders
for i in range(len(Inps)):
  ##Iterates through current pallet amounts
  for j in range(len(PallSums)):
    ##selects match on item, and if qty required is <= qty existing
    if Inps.loc[i, "Item"] == PallSums.loc[j, "Item"] and Inps.loc[i, "Qty"] <= PallSums.loc[j, "Qty"]:
      #Removes required quantity from existing quantity
      PallSums.loc[j, "Qty"] = PallSums.loc[j, "Qty"] - Inps.loc[i, "Qty"]
      #Breaks so it only removes the quantity once
      break
    else:
      #continues to loop through
      continue
```

This works fine, but if the `Inps.loc[i, "Qty"]<= PallSums.loc[j, "Qty"]` isn't met at any point then I am not capturing this.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you can use the relatively uncommon `for...else` (where the `else` triggers if the loop terminates naturally but not on a break):

```
In [1]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     if i == 11:
   ...:         print("found 11")
   ...:         break
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("didn't find 11")
   ...:
didn't find 11
```

-

```
In [2]: for i in range(20):
   ...:     if i == 11:
   ...:         print("found 11")
   ...:         break
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("didn't find 11")
   ...:
found 11
```